# Mutating webhook doc reference

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, mutation

We are using the kubernetes mutating webhook to mutate a request on creation of a pod. From what I understand, the api server makes a callback to an endpoint of a mutating web hook that matches certain rules of a request. The webhook now mutates the request by adding patches to it and sending it back to the api server.

An example patch:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/metadata/annotations",
    "value": {
      "injected": "true"
    }
  }
]
```

My question is this - Is there a reference or a doc that shows how the patch endpoints work. I am referring to `metadata/annotations` here.

I have questions like -

- does it update the existing object or does it replace it?
- what other operations are possible other than `add`

There are several more patch endpoints for different objects. I have been trying to find these docs for some time now and couldn't.

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this. Sorry if it isn't. Kindly point me to the right forum if there is one.

Comment: can you link your reference pls?

Comment: What reference ??

Answer (score 1):

Mutating webhook does not patch an object because the object is not yet persisted in ETCD. Mutating web hooks gets a [request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#request) from API Server. This request has AdmissionReview object in it.Mutating Webhook unmarshalls the AdmissionReview object, mutates it and then send back a [response](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#response) to API Server.

You will start with a basic web server, that supports SSL/TLS, and can read and respond in JSON format.In practice, you can use whatever programming language you’d like for this.Ideally though, use a language that already has K8S libraries so you don’t have to create our own object types; Go (naturally) has these, but there are also at least Python libraries you could use.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.13.0/test/images/webhook/main.go) in go.

Comment: Yeah I should've been clearer. It doesn't patch an object, it mutates the request. I am asking for the doc on the various ways this mutation can happen.

Comment: AFAIK There is no doc as such...but there are enough examples and mutation will depend on use cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I am asking for the doc on the various ways this mutation can happen.

I think this can be found in [this design proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/api-machinery/admission-control-webhooks.md#use-case-analysis).